# Adapt JComboxBox maximumRowCount to JFrame or Screen Size

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

Everything is in the title.

In my application, depending on a selection made by the user I fill up a combobox with a list which can sometime be small (1 element) sometimes be large (150 elements).

What I would like is not to have a fixed height set at startup to a given value but to set the maximumRowCount to the height of my JFrame or to the height of my  screen and I don't know how to determine the number of rows that would match my application height or my screen height. This should be dynamical (at runtime) so when I change the combobox font size the maximumRowCount also adapts itself.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you need to figure out how big each row in the drop-down list is.  To do this, the *easy* way is to create a cell renderer, populate it, and ask it for its preferred height.

```
final DefaultListCellRenderer dlcr = new DefaultListCellRenderer();
dlcr.setText("one of my combo items");

int numRows = (int)( (1.0f * frame.getHeight()) / dlcr.getPreferredSize().height );

setMaximumRowCount(numRows);
```

Note that I used `frame.getHeight()` here, but at least in some look-and-feels, the drop-down list starts below the combo box, so you'd have to make some adjustment for that.  And there are ways to get the size of a screen, too, such as those in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html.

Comment: no need to get low-level. Instead configure the renderering component with some data contained in the list and ask it's prefSize

Comment: Sorry for my very late answer. I checked the code and it is working fine. And the idea is so simple thanks Kleopatra and thanks to you Rob for writing it down.

Answer (score 3):

Below is a code snippet which sets the rowCount dynamically

The basic steps

- get the pref size of the rendering component
- get the location of the combo relative to the context you want (the example takes the screen) and the available space below
- calculate the number of rows which fit into the available space
- do all this in a PopupMenuListener to be really dynamical

The code (which is obviously not production quality, just to give you something to play with :-)

```
    final JComboBox box = new JComboBox(new Object[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 34,3,3});
    PopupMenuListener l = new PopupMenuListener() {

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeVisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
            int pref = getRowHeight(box);
            int available = getAvailableScreenHeightBelow(box);
            int count = available / pref;
            box.setMaximumRowCount(count);
        }

        private int getRowHeight(final JComboBox box) {
            // note: here we assume the rendering comp's pref is the same for all rows
            ComboPopup popup = (ComboPopup) box.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(0);
            ListCellRenderer renderer = box.getRenderer();
            Component comp = renderer.getListCellRendererComponent(popup.getList(), 1, 0, false, false);
            int pref = comp.getPreferredSize().height;
            return pref;
        }

        private int getAvailableScreenHeightBelow(final JComboBox box) {
            // note: this is crude - f.i. doesn't take taskbar into account 
            Dimension screen = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
            Point location = box.getLocationOnScreen();
            location.y += box.getHeight();
            int available = screen.height - location.y;
            return available;
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuWillBecomeInvisible(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void popupMenuCanceled(PopupMenuEvent e) {
        }
    };

    box.addPopupMenuListener(l);
```